# Changing name of saved places from coordinates in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating a list of saved places on Google Maps, some are not already saved locations so I'm labeling them then adding to the list. However, on the list, they displayed as coordinates, not the label.  Can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature is not available. However, there are two options for how to mark them:

- **label them with a custom name**

  > [image: 1]
  >   [image: 2]

### _______________________________________________________________

- **add a custom note to such place**

  > [image: 1]
  >   [image: 1]
  >   [image: 5]